# Linking two elements on mouseover and dual tooltips

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover

I'm looking for some advice on how to get two elements in a visualization, which are linked by a common data value, to respond simultaneously.

Here is the visualization as it stands now.
http://bl.ocks.org/natemiller/2686e5c0d9a1a4bb0895

Note that the different colored points are for the 50 US states in 2005 (green) and 2013 (blue), so there is a blue point and a green point for each state. I have two things I would like to get working here.

1. I would like to be able to mouseover either a blue point or a green point and have the corresponding point (for the same state) highlighted.
2. I would like a tooltip with some basic data to appear next to both points, providing point specific data.

Regarding the first point above. Right now when you mouseover a blue point the corresponding green point is highlighted, however, when you mouseover a green point only that point is highlighted and not its corresponding blue point. I imagine this is a simple fix, but for the life of me I can't figure out to reverse the reference so I get green to blue references as well.

Regarding the second point. Right now a tooltip with relevant information appears near the moused-over point, but I would like to have a similar tooltip appear next to the corresponding point from the alternate year of data, so that direct comparisons across years are easier. I am quite new to adding HTML tooltips so I'm not clear on how to do this and suspect it may require a new method for adding tooltips. Can any help to steer me in the correct direction for how to have a tooltip appear near the moused-over element and a corresponding linked element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remember that ids are unique and you're creating multiple circles with the same id, use a class instead

```
circles.attr("class", function(d) { return d.state })
```

2) You're creating a single tooltip, if you want to show one for each pair of states create multiple tooltips

Assuming that you make these changes you can easily create multiple tooltips for each pair of states

```
circles.on('mouseover', function (d) {
  // selection for 2 states
  var states = d3.selectAll('circle.' + d.state)
  // code to style those nodes goes here ...

  // tooltips for the states
  var tooltips = d3.select('svg').selectAll('text.tooltip')
    .data(states.data())

  // initial styling of the tooltips goes here...
  tooltips
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'tooltip')

  // update
  tooltips
    .html(function (d) {
      // text of the tooltip
      return 'something'
    })
    // positioning, it requires some margin fixes I guess
    .attr('x', function (d) { return xScale(d.child_pov) })
    .attr('y', function (d) { return yScale(d.non_math_prof) })
})
```

Finally remove the tooltips created on mouseover when the mouseout event is triggered

```
circles.on('mouseout', function (d) {
  d3.select('svg').selectAll('text.tooltip').remove()
})
```

Comment: Thank you. I implemented that and it looks good, but both tooltips provide the same data, for just the moused-over element. No matter which dot is moused-over I would like both dots to have a tooltip (as they do thanks to your code), but have each tooltip provide point specific information (year, state, x, y). It seems like I have use data for "circle.state" for color highlighting and then within that "circle.state.year" for proper tooltip data. Can this type of things be done?

Comment: Well the data is initially bound to each circle so doing 'circle.{state}' is just a way to get a pair of circles, they still have the initial data stored within them, using this data you can set the text to whatever you want, if you pass a function the data for each circle will be available as the first argument

Comment: Looks great. Thank you. These tooltips are just text. What would be the best way from here to give them a background so that the text is legible on top of the background data points.

Comment: I'd use a `<g>` tag which has a `<rect>` for the background and the `<text>` tag you already have, if it sounds complicated you can use `<div>` instead of svg elements, note that if you use divs and put them in the body instead of the svg tag you need to do more calculations for their positioning since the top/left coordinates would be absolute, anyways I'd go for the `g` tag nested with anything I want

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same id. Use a class `.circleHawaii` instead of an id `#circleHawaii`.